# How to fix issue in Heroku '[heroku-exec] ERROR: Could not connect to proxy! Waiting 20 seconds before retry...'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-api

Heroku after Scheduling in the SpringBoot app throw the following exceptions:

```
[heroku-exec] ERROR: Could not connect to proxy! Waiting 10 seconds before retry...
[heroku-exec] ERROR: Could not connect to proxy! Waiting 20 seconds before retry...
```

System: Heroku, SpringBoot, org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling

I interrupted it via restart.

What does it mean in my context and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an exception that's thrown from your app. It's a warning that the [Heroku Exec process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec) cannot connect to the proxy that allows you to run commands like `heroku ps:exec` or `heroku java:jconsole`. There are many reasons this can happen (network blips, etc).

It's safe to ignore this, as long as you don't those commands. Otherwise you can disable by running:

```
$ heroku features:disable runtime-heroku-exec
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I guess this is the reason why I catched the exception.